# url append issue

Tags: html, smarty

I am having some strange problem, please see following...

at current url...

http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/

and following html

```
<a href="?srtby=relevance">Relevance</a> //on click url becomes http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtby=relevance
<a href="?srtby=views">Views</a> //on click url becomes http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtby=views



<a href="?srtbydate=today">Today</a>
```

On click url becomes http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtbydate=today instead of http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtby=relevance?srtbydate=today

I don't why is this happening? Please suggest. thanks.

Comment: You don't understand why what is happening?

Comment: You only get one query string. Because you've specified a new querystring it replaces the currently active one, and wont append to it.

Comment: `<a href="?srtby=relevance?srtbydate=today">`?

Comment: The correct separator for query strings is the `&` character. `?srtby=relevance&srtbydate=today` would be correct.

Comment: @zzzzBov you got my problem, this is the problem. but if i add `&` character what would happen if user click `<a href="&srtbydate=today">Relevance</a>` before `<a href="?srtby=views">Views</a>` then url becomes `http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/&srtbydate=today`

Comment: @seoppc, that's not how links work. You're using PHP, so you'll have to output the current query string in addition to `srtbydate=today`.

Comment: ok, so i will use php then for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the query string and appending it to the current URL. You only use the ? once, and then to append extra vars use & e.g.

?var1=relevance&var2=views

This allows you to pass multiple params.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a query on  the end of a URL, like this:

```
http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtby=relevance
```

Any links you subsequently click with remove or replace that query string.  So clicking a link with the href of

```
?srtby=thisotherthing
```

Takes you to http://localhost/web/gallery/test/scs/?srtby=thisotherthing

These parameter's don't "stack" - the link you click would have to include any and all query parameters for them to appear on the following page.

Comment: You'd need to modify any URLs in the page to include the current query string parameters.  Smarty might be able to help, or you could use a jQuery script to modify the URLs.

Comment: can you provide any example please?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. What is happening is you are rewriting the query string with your URL and it does not append, it merely replaces. To fix this, in your code you would want to build your URLS by appending or replacing the content. The easiest way is by building your query strings outside in objects and then serializing it to a query string.

**Update:** An easy way to do it in PHP

```
<?php
    $currentQuery = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $url = array();
    parse_str($currentQuery, $url);
    $url['srtby'] = 'views';
?>
<a href="<?php echo http_build_query($url); ?>">Link</a>
```

Note that the above requires PHP 5.

Comment: you have got the issue and it would be awesome if you could post an example as well.